# resource style/LaunchTheme not found

Tags: android, dart, icons, flutter

I just changed the icon for my app to a newer one and now whenever i try to build and run the app i get the following error:

```
 Project\build\app\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml:49: AAPT: 
 error: resource style/LaunchTheme (aka 
 com.example.project:style/LaunchTheme) not found.
```

I used the flutter_launcher_icon package to make the icons and I have tried the solutions provided online but none of them seemed to help

[image: Android file directory]

Comment: take a screenshot of your directory structure inside android folder , also put the LaunchTheme xml file

Comment: @diegoveloper i have added a screenshot of the android directory and I am not sure where to place the LaunchTheme xml file, the app used to work completely fine without it before.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Ok, looks like you don't have your `styles.xml` file which has the theme.

Create a file named  `styles.xml` inside the folder `res/values` and add this content:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <resources>
        <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
                 Flutter draws its first frame -->
            <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
            <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item> 
        </style>
    </resources>
```

Comment: Life saviour <3

Answer (score 7):

I solve like this my androidmanifest-> call NormalTheme but my styles.xml folder has LaunchTheme so i change the name problem has solved :)

Comment: `android:resource="@style/LaunchTheme"`

Answer (score 0):

shortEdges
    @color/staticSplashScreenBackgroundColor
    @color/staticSplashScreenBackgroundColor
    @color/staticSplashScreenBackgroundColor
    0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).